# How do you remove &#8217; from a text string and replace it with '?

Tags: angularjs, regex, wordpress

I have the following string:

```
var string = "<p>How well does Angular Work? We&#8217;re about to see!
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam vehicula 
imperdiet sapien, placerat vulputate sem bibendum id. In hac habitasse 
platea dictumst. Nulla enim lectus, laoreet non posuere at, ultricies id 
leo. Nullam nec eros lacus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
adipiscing elit. Integer egestas scelerisque [&hellip;]</p> "
```

I use the following regex filter:

```
string.replace(/<\/?[^>]+>/gi, '');
```

Then I get:

```
How well does Angular Work? We&#8217;re about to see! Lorem ipsum dolor 
sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam vehicula imperdiet sapien, 
placerat vulputate sem bibendum id. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nulla 
enim lectus, laoreet non posuere at, ultricies id leo. Nullam nec eros 
lacus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer 
egestas scelerisque [&hellip;]
```

As you can see, the apostrophe in "We're" is returning `&#8217;`  and `[&hellip;]` is at the end of **string** instead of [...].  I'm getting this this string from Wordpress and I want to put it in my own html page.  When the filter is done I should get:

```
How well does Angular Work? We're about to see! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam vehicula imperdiet sapien, placerat 
vulputate sem bibendum id. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nulla enim 
lectus, laoreet non posuere at, ultricies id leo. Nullam nec eros lacus. 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer egestas 
scelerisque. . .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`ngBindHTML`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) directive to insert html into the DOM in a specified element.

Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DoZxssa406SJFaNAiOSs?p=preview) with your example...